# Prestashop does not run locally (XAMPP, Windows 10)

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.4

I migrated prestashop 1.4 (all the files) from the live site, to my computer and imported the database successfully to htdocs/prestashop
Now I go to http://localhost/prestashop/ and it shows nothing but this

> "This page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Check the server logs to investigate. Have you enabled the display errors?

Comment: You mean from apache? There are a couple of them. Which one do you want me to post?

Comment: https://ufile.io/73g67 and https://ufile.io/ggjh4

Comment: have you enable errors in config/defines.inc.php? set define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false) to true so you can see error in your page

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run PS 1.4 on php7.

`mysql_connect` was deprecated in php5.5 and completely removed in php7.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Yeah, thanks that was the case. Now I have another issue though. "Link to database cannot be established." xD I keep running into problems. Can't believe people actually make money selling these prehistoric versions of websites.

Comment: OK I fixed the issue (with the help of another forum too) , it needed some changes in the credentials, since the default user for phpmyadmin uses no password. My settings file used a password, so they didn't mach. Thanks a lot for your help though, it steered me at the right direction ^^